# he!p me to train YOLOv3-tiny or YOLOv4-tiny on Google Colab

Tags: python, yolo

I'm new at coding but I want use yolo algorithm for my autonomous plane but I cant train yolo tiny versions on Google colab. If you have a video about how to train yolo easily please share with me. I have 850 photo about  UAV and I made bounding box to photos and I have 1700 files. Please help to train tiny version of yolo.

I tried to train Yolov4-tiny on Google Colab .this link for Google Colab https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1hQO4nOoD6RDxdbz3C1YSiifTsyZjZpYm?usp=sharing

and I get this error

```
CUDA-version: 11000 (11020), cuDNN: 7.6.5, CUDNN_HALF=1, GPU count: 1  
 CUDNN_HALF=1 
 OpenCV version: 3.2.0
 Prepare additional network for mAP calculation...
 0 : compute_capability = 370, cudnn_half = 0, GPU: Tesla K80 
net.optimized_memory = 0 
mini_batch = 1, batch = 16, time_steps = 1, train = 0 
   layer   filters  size/strd(dil)      input                output
   0 Create CUDA-stream - 0 
 Create cudnn-handle 0 
conv     32       3 x 3/ 2    416 x 416 x   3 ->  208 x 208 x  32 0.075 BF
   1 conv     64       3 x 3/ 2    208 x 208 x  32 ->  104 x 104 x  64 0.399 BF
   2 conv     64       3 x 3/ 1    104 x 104 x  64 ->  104 x 104 x  64 0.797 BF
   3 route  2                              1/2 ->  104 x 104 x  32 
   4 conv     32       3 x 3/ 1    104 x 104 x  32 ->  104 x 104 x  32 0.199 BF
   5 conv     32       3 x 3/ 1    104 x 104 x  32 ->  104 x 104 x  32 0.199 BF
   6 route  5 4                                ->  104 x 104 x  64 
   7 conv     64       1 x 1/ 1    104 x 104 x  64 ->  104 x 104 x  64 0.089 BF
   8 route  2 7                                ->  104 x 104 x 128 
   9 max                2x 2/ 2    104 x 104 x 128 ->   52 x  52 x 128 0.001 BF
  10 conv    128       3 x 3/ 1     52 x  52 x 128 ->   52 x  52 x 128 0.797 BF
  11 route  10                             1/2 ->   52 x  52 x  64 
  12 conv     64       3 x 3/ 1     52 x  52 x  64 ->   52 x  52 x  64 0.199 BF
  13 conv     64       3 x 3/ 1     52 x  52 x  64 ->   52 x  52 x  64 0.199 BF
  14 route  13 12                              ->   52 x  52 x 128 
  15 conv    128       1 x 1/ 1     52 x  52 x 128 ->   52 x  52 x 128 0.089 BF
  16 route  10 15                              ->   52 x  52 x 256 
  17 max                2x 2/ 2     52 x  52 x 256 ->   26 x  26 x 256 0.001 BF
  18 conv    256       3 x 3/ 1     26 x  26 x 256 ->   26 x  26 x 256 0.797 BF
  19 route  18                             1/2 ->   26 x  26 x 128 
  20 conv    128       3 x 3/ 1     26 x  26 x 128 ->   26 x  26 x 128 0.199 BF
  21 conv    128       3 x 3/ 1     26 x  26 x 128 ->   26 x  26 x 128 0.199 BF
  22 route  21 20                              ->   26 x  26 x 256 
  23 conv    256       1 x 1/ 1     26 x  26 x 256 ->   26 x  26 x 256 0.089 BF
  24 route  18 23                              ->   26 x  26 x 512 
  25 max                2x 2/ 2     26 x  26 x 512 ->   13 x  13 x 512 0.000 BF
  26 conv    512       3 x 3/ 1     13 x  13 x 512 ->   13 x  13 x 512 0.797 BF
  27 conv    256       1 x 1/ 1     13 x  13 x 512 ->   13 x  13 x 256 0.044 BF
  28 conv    512       3 x 3/ 1     13 x  13 x 256 ->   13 x  13 x 512 0.399 BF
  29 conv     18       1 x 1/ 1     13 x  13 x 512 ->   13 x  13 x  18 0.003 BF
  30 yolo
[yolo] params: iou loss: ciou (4), iou_norm: 0.07, obj_norm: 1.00, cls_norm: 1.00, delta_norm: 1.00, scale_x_y: 1.05
nms_kind: greedynms (1), beta = 0.600000 
  31 route  27                                 ->   13 x  13 x 256 
  32 conv    128       1 x 1/ 1     13 x  13 x 256 ->   13 x  13 x 128 0.011 BF
  33 upsample                 2x    13 x  13 x 128 ->   26 x  26 x 128
  34 route  33 23                              ->   26 x  26 x 384 
  35 conv    256       3 x 3/ 1     26 x  26 x 384 ->   26 x  26 x 256 1.196 BF
  36 conv     18       1 x 1/ 1     26 x  26 x 256 ->   26 x  26 x  18 0.006 BF
  37 yolo
[yolo] params: iou loss: ciou (4), iou_norm: 0.07, obj_norm: 1.00, cls_norm: 1.00, delta_norm: 1.00, scale_x_y: 1.05
nms_kind: greedynms (1), beta = 0.600000 
Total BFLOPS 6.787 
avg_outputs = 299663 
 Allocate additional workspace_size = 12.46 MB 
yolov4-tiny-custom
 0 : compute_capability = 370, cudnn_half = 0, GPU: Tesla K80 
net.optimized_memory = 0 
mini_batch = 4, batch = 64, time_steps = 1, train = 1 
   layer   filters  size/strd(dil)      input                output
   0 conv     32       3 x 3/ 2    416 x 416 x   3 ->  208 x 208 x  32 0.075 BF
   1 conv     64       3 x 3/ 2    208 x 208 x  32 ->  104 x 104 x  64 0.399 BF
   2 conv     64       3 x 3/ 1    104 x 104 x  64 ->  104 x 104 x  64 0.797 BF
   3 route  2                              1/2 ->  104 x 104 x  32 
   4 conv     32       3 x 3/ 1    104 x 104 x  32 ->  104 x 104 x  32 0.199 BF
   5 conv     32       3 x 3/ 1    104 x 104 x  32 ->  104 x 104 x  32 0.199 BF
   6 route  5 4                                ->  104 x 104 x  64 
   7 conv     64       1 x 1/ 1    104 x 104 x  64 ->  104 x 104 x  64 0.089 BF
   8 route  2 7                                ->  104 x 104 x 128 
   9 max                2x 2/ 2    104 x 104 x 128 ->   52 x  52 x 128 0.001 BF
  10 conv    128       3 x 3/ 1     52 x  52 x 128 ->   52 x  52 x 128 0.797 BF
  11 route  10                             1/2 ->   52 x  52 x  64 
  12 conv     64       3 x 3/ 1     52 x  52 x  64 ->   52 x  52 x  64 0.199 BF
  13 conv     64       3 x 3/ 1     52 x  52 x  64 ->   52 x  52 x  64 0.199 BF
  14 route  13 12                              ->   52 x  52 x 128 
  15 conv    128       1 x 1/ 1     52 x  52 x 128 ->   52 x  52 x 128 0.089 BF
  16 route  10 15                              ->   52 x  52 x 256 
  17 max                2x 2/ 2     52 x  52 x 256 ->   26 x  26 x 256 0.001 BF
  18 conv    256       3 x 3/ 1     26 x  26 x 256 ->   26 x  26 x 256 0.797 BF
  19 route  18                             1/2 ->   26 x  26 x 128 
  20 conv    128       3 x 3/ 1     26 x  26 x 128 ->   26 x  26 x 128 0.199 BF
  21 conv    128       3 x 3/ 1     26 x  26 x 128 ->   26 x  26 x 128 0.199 BF
  22 route  21 20                              ->   26 x  26 x 256 
  23 conv    256       1 x 1/ 1     26 x  26 x 256 ->   26 x  26 x 256 0.089 BF
  24 route  18 23                              ->   26 x  26 x 512 
  25 max                2x 2/ 2     26 x  26 x 512 ->   13 x  13 x 512 0.000 BF
  26 conv    512       3 x 3/ 1     13 x  13 x 512 ->   13 x  13 x 512 0.797 BF
  27 conv    256       1 x 1/ 1     13 x  13 x 512 ->   13 x  13 x 256 0.044 BF
  28 conv    512       3 x 3/ 1     13 x  13 x 256 ->   13 x  13 x 512 0.399 BF
  29 conv     18       1 x 1/ 1     13 x  13 x 512 ->   13 x  13 x  18 0.003 BF
  30 yolo
[yolo] params: iou loss: ciou (4), iou_norm: 0.07, obj_norm: 1.00, cls_norm: 1.00, delta_norm: 1.00, scale_x_y: 1.05
nms_kind: greedynms (1), beta = 0.600000 
  31 route  27                                 ->   13 x  13 x 256 
  32 conv    128       1 x 1/ 1     13 x  13 x 256 ->   13 x  13 x 128 0.011 BF
  33 upsample                 2x    13 x  13 x 128 ->   26 x  26 x 128
  34 route  33 23                              ->   26 x  26 x 384 
  35 conv    256       3 x 3/ 1     26 x  26 x 384 ->   26 x  26 x 256 1.196 BF
  36 conv     18       1 x 1/ 1     26 x  26 x 256 ->   26 x  26 x  18 0.006 BF
  37 yolo
[yolo] params: iou loss: ciou (4), iou_norm: 0.07, obj_norm: 1.00, cls_norm: 1.00, delta_norm: 1.00, scale_x_y: 1.05
nms_kind: greedynms (1), beta = 0.600000 
Total BFLOPS 6.787 
avg_outputs = 299663 
 Allocate additional workspace_size = 99.68 MB 
Loading weights from yolov4-tiny.conv.29...
 seen 64, trained: 0 K-images (0 Kilo-batches_64) 
Done! Loaded 29 layers from weights-file 
Learning Rate: 0.00261, Momentum: 0.9, Decay: 0.0005
 Detection layer: 30 - type = 28 
 Detection layer: 37 - type = 28 
 Create 6 permanent cpu-threads
```

Please help me.(Sorry for my Bad English.)

Comment: you can read this article (have video also). https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/train-a-custom-yolov4-tiny-object-detector-using-google-colab-b58be08c9593

Comment: I read that article but I got error on training step I wrote error